# auto scroll on move rows in Tabulator.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I am using tabulator(4.9). I have 100 rows in my table. Furthermore, I want to move the 100th row to the first position, while moving the auto scroll is not working. Is there any possible to enable the auto scroll.

Comment: Apparently this is a broswer-specific issue: doesn't work in Chrome or Firefox. Does work in Safari. https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3137

Comment: Example to test: https://jsfiddle.net/janvrska/k70L2scr/20/

Answer (score 0):

Set this

paginationSize:100,

after class="tabulator-tableHolder" to set height as you need

so content are scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried. But it's not working

Comment: use important for css and i have already tried and it's work so.

Answer (score 0):

Seemingly, if you remove the handler, the scroll works; I've tried with the sample provided by "spring" above in the comments with the handler removed and it worked.

EDIT: just tried modifying the row handler column initialization options and, only by removing `formatter: "handle"` the scroll starts working, you don't need to remove the whole handler.